# cronのログについて

Tags: centos, cron

**前提**
・cronを毎日実行しています
・phpを実行させ複数のhtmlファイルを出力させています
・(出力指定順番が最後ではない)ある特定のhtmlファイルだけが最近になって出力されなくなり原因を調べています

---

**Q1**
・/var/log/cronを確認したら、下記のような感じになっていたのですが、毎日実行しているのに、特定の日しかログが出ないのはなぜだと考えられますか？
・この日しかエラーは出なかったということ？

> cron 
>   cron-20180702
>    cron-20180708

---

**Q2.cronのログ出力設定するやり方とかありますか？**
・cronのログ出力レベルを設定したりは出来ない？？

---

**Q3.cronメールについて**
・cron実行時に受信できるメール内容と、/var/log/cronの内容は同じですか？
・/var/log/cronの内容を確認するなら、わざわざcronメールを受信する必要はない？？

---

**環境**
・CentOS7

Comment: http://shima-nigoro.hatenablog.jp/entry/2016/06/12/182903 の記事が参考になるのでは?(google cron log level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

実際に動いているかどうかは、/var/log/cron ログの中身を確認して タイムスタンプを確認すると良いと思います。

◆ログの例

```
Jul  8 06:00:01 hoge CROND[28126]: (root) CMD (/usr/share/clamav/freshclam-sleep)
Jul  8 06:01:01 hoge CROND[28158]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
```

日付つきの2つのファイルは おそらく logroate によって ローテーションされたものです。

cron (cronie) は rsyslog の設定で ログレベルを制御することができます。
ただ、デフォルトでは、すべてを出力しているので、ログの量を減らすことは出来ても、追加の情報を得ることはできないと思います。
※有用かどうかはわかりませんが crond の `-x` オプションでデバッグ情報を出力できるようです。

cron実行結果のメールは、実行されたコマンドが出力した 標準出力と標準エラー出力の内容です。
/var/log/cron に書かれているのは crond が出力したもので 内容は異なります。